# Nested selectors starting with tbody with pseudo-selectors on them

Tags: css-selectors, webstorm, pseudo-element, stylus

I am having constant problem with some pseudo-selectors in WebStorm/Stylus/angular-cli.

I am new to stylus, so it might be something I overlooked in the docs especially that the problematic selectors do not get compiled into css.

Please have a look at the screenshot. It shows a combination of selectors and pseudo-elements which I think are perfectly valid. Initially I suspected that having double pseudo-selectors could be considered invalid, but apparently it's about the selectors starting with `tbody`.

Can anyone define the problem better?

[image]

---

**Edit**

What fixes the syntax is when I use the `>` operator - be it on the first selector only:

[image]

Comment: The two-colon notation is for pseudo elements; pseudo classes still use a single colon.

Comment: As you can see I've tried both notations, and neither seems to pass through.

Comment: Stylus has no problem compiling any type of selector. What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting WebStorm syntax errors plus the selectors don't seem to get compiled.